# Can I use the {Invisible} tag on an item frame?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a floating item, and the best way I could think of was to make an invulnerable invisible item frame. I tried this command:

```
/summon minecraft:item_frame ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:diamond,Count:1},Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1}
```

It did summon an item frame but I could see it and the item. What happened?

Comment: Maybe if you name the item frame and make things that have that name turn invisible. I do it with animals sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Skylinerw said, item frames cannot be made invisible.

However, you just want to make a floating item. You can summon an item that won't despawn which players can't pick up. On top of that, you can use the `NoGravity` tag which will allow the item to float in mid-air. Combining these 3 abilities, you can summon the item using this command:

```
/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:stone,Count:1},Age:-32768,PickupDelay:32767,NoGravity:1}
```

If you do not like that the item is spinning around, you can use a second method where an invisible armor stand has the item in his head slot using this command:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1,NoGravity:1,Marker:1,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:stone,Count:1b}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Invisible` tag is specifically for armor stands. Item frames cannot be made invisible.

You can find a list of NBT data [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Entity_format), which tells you which tags belong to what entities.